# How to set variable, pass it to a partial file and remove it after?

Tags: php, loop

I am looking on how to include variable only when needed into a partial which is loaded for every loop. 
I have tried `set_query_var` which works good for including variable but seems like my usage of `remove_query_var` after doesn't work properly. What am I missing? [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/remove_query_var/) doesn't say much although it has been added only recently (4.5.0 version)

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
    <?php
    // Set variable for partial
    $schema_markup = true; 
    set_query_var('schema_markup', $schema_markup);

    while ($query->have_posts())  :
        $query->the_post(); 

    // Load partial view 
    get_template_part('partials/loop/post-xs');

    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Remove variable so that it doesn't trigger when partials are called later in the page where microdata is not needed
    global $wp;
    $wp->remove_query_var('schema_markup');
    ?>
</ul>
```

Starting code inside `partials/loop/post-xs`

```
<li <?php if(!empty($schema_markup)) echo 'itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"'; ?>>
```

Comment: `remove_query_var` removes it from the list of public query vars, not from the query object after a query has already run.